# Windows Phone app Approval process

Tags: windows-phone-7

How strict/loose are Microsoft on approving Windows Phone apps submitted to the marketplace? I know there are tonnes of stories of developers having their iphone apps rejected on unreasonable grounds, and I know Google let you publish just about anything to the Android market...how are your experiences with WM platform?

Any comments are appreciated so thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, nothing has been removed or rejected unexpectedly. As long as you follow the guidelines set out in the [Application Certification Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184843%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), you should be fine. If an app is rejected, they give guidelines on how to reproduce the problem as well as explain what they expected the app to do, so it's a helpful response.

Answer (score 2):

Read the docs on the Windows Phone site.

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/

I have found them to be VERY strict but only for things in their guidelines.  Like anything follow them and you can't go wrong!